# How I use multiply(*), add(+) divide (/) to be hotkey (shortcut key)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make "add(+)" "multiply(*)" "divide(/)" as hotkeys but following the code I attached they can not do for that

```js
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
  var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
  if (keycode == '111') {
    $('#someTextBox').focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="someTextBox" />
```

Comment: $(document).keypress(function(event){
                var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
                if(keycode == '111'){
                    $('#someTextBox').focus();
                }
            });

I have try this

Comment: I made you a proper snippet  to show a  [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html does not show 111 as a one of +,/,* on keypress

```js
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
  var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
  $('#someTextBox').val(keycode)
  if ([42,43,47].indexOf(keycode) > -1) {
    $('#someTextBox').focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="someTextBox" />
```